# Use of Global objects in vba Office macros

Tags: vba, global-variables, ms-word

Please explain the following:

1. What is the difference between Word.Application and Word.Global?
2. In a VBA Word macro, are references to  Global objects like Application and Selection always bound to Word or could they inadvertently refer to Excel objects if Excel is running in the foreground?
3. If I want to open Word, start a (long, complicated) macro running and then switch focus to another application e.g. Excel, do I need to modify references to globals like ActiveDocument, Application and Selection to explicitly point to the Word version of the object so that they are not confused with the Excel version of the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `Word.Global`, can you clarify? Preferably with some example of code that uses such a call.

> In a VBA Word macro, are references to Global objects like Application and Selection always bound to Word or could they inadvertently refer to Excel objects if Excel is running in the foreground?

Unless otherwise qualified, `Application` always refers to the current application object. If your VBA is in Word, then this will always return the Word.Application object.

> If I want to open Word, start a (long, complicated) macro running and then switch focus to another application e.g. Excel,

The macro in Word won't be confused by other foreground tasks, but the Word Application may not be responsive during the macro's runtime.

You may need to take measures to prevent the Word Application from taking focus during run-time. For most applications including yours though I don't think this will present a problem. As you split the document in to several "new" documents, create new Document objects and assign the visible=False:

```
Set doc = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, David. I'm not sure binding is what I'm after. The scenario I have is as follows:  A user opens word to run a macro which splits a large document into several sub-documents.

Comment: The macro takes a significant time to run (2-15mins depending on size and complexity of the source document). Whilst this macro is running, the user wants to complete some tasks entirely unrelated to the macro being run. E.g. they want to open an unrelated document to work on, or they want to check their email etc. I want to ensure that they the user can run new, unrelated foreground tasks without confusing the macro which is running... I hope my ramblings are making sense ...

Comment: Well you specifically said "I want to open word, start a (long, complicated) macro running and then switch focus to another application e.g. Excel" which I interpret as "I want my Word macro to manipulate Excel objects" -- this is a fairly common request although usually it's the other way around (Excel manipulating Word or PowerPoint, etc.).

Comment: The macro itself won't be confused by other foreground tasks, but the Word Application may not be responsive during the macro's runtime.

Comment: Thanks - that's just what I wanted to hear :-)

Comment: BTW: I came across Word.Global being compared with Word.Application on the following thread: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1741171 I guess that somewhat confused me ...

Comment: I can't follow that thread really. But in any case, you can always rely on [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841702(v=office.14).aspx), see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837254(v=office.14).aspx) for the `Global` object and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838565(v=office.14).aspx) for the `Application` object.

Comment: BTW, the way this site works is by "accepting" answers which have solved your question/problem, so if my answer has been helpful, please consider marking as accepted.